# TotalResultsDaemon running as root

Tags: mojave, virus

Someone I know's macOS Mojave got taken over by something called TotalResults.

In the process list it shows a lot of processes TotalResults running as root. There were signs in Chrome first, some extension and a weird gateway setting.

I couldn't find anything about this. Anyone else? Let me know before I wipe the machine

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot with TotalResultsDaemon as root]

Answer (score 1):

Before you go all the way to wipe, try

```
sudo rm -r /var/root/.TotalResults
```

in Terminal, followed by a restart.

Comment: Too late but once something has root on a machine removing stuff seems not sufficient to me

Comment: @miiimooo Agreed. I wonder about your "I did a re-install plus a wipe but it's still there" comment though. If it's still there after a wipe it seems kind of strange.

Comment: actually that part of the comment confused me too when I reread it. It's definitely cone since I completely wiped it. Maybe I meant I did a re-install first and it was still there and then I wiped it (it's now gone).
Strange though that no one else has ever had this..